# Rails - link to new action instead of show if an item doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a link so that if the current user has a project already created, then they just click the 'Project' link, and it will take them to their project. Each user can only have one project. If they don't have a project, then it will instead take them to the form to create one (i.e. the new view/action).

How would I go about this? I apologise, I'm new to rails. At the moment, I am using the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Project', project_path %>
```

which works fine if the user already has a project, but says "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects"}" if one doesn't exist. I'm not sure where to start - do I add in conditions to the link_to, or is it something I need to put in the controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Project', 
      current_user.project.present? ? 
        project_path(current_user.project) : 
        new_project_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should check it inside the `new` action. Find project if exist and redirect to the `edit` action.

If you will decide which link to render user can cheat you and type `/projects/new` in address bar.